# How to create markers on click of geojson component?

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm trying to add markers when a user clicks on a certain Geojson feature.  I'm new to react and react-leaflet and am trying to use the useState hook to accomplish this task.  I've been stuck a couple of days on this issue.

Here is my **App.js**.  I import data, create a state variable and setter for my markers, and pass those items to my components `<MyData/>` and `<MyMarkers/>`.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {MapContainer, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import someData from './data.geojson'

import MyData from './components/MyData.js'
import MyMarkers from './components/MyMarkers.js'


// import bugged marker
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

// set the default icon
let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon,
    shadowUrl: iconShadow,
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40],
});
L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;




export default function App() {
  // create state variable and setter for the markers
  let [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])
  // import geojson data
  let data= JSON.parse(someData)

  return (
    <>
   <MapContainer
      doubleClickZoom={false}
      id="mapId"
      zoom={14}
      center={[37.37569444, -91.5528056]}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
        attribution="Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Sources: GEBCO, NOAA, CHS, OSU, UNH, CSUMB, National Geographic, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, and Esri"
      />

    <MyData data={data} markers = {markers} setMarkers ={setMarkers}/> 
    {markers.length >0 && <MyMarkers markers={markers}/>}

    </MapContainer>
   </>
  );
}
```

Here is my **MyData** component which displays the geojson data.  It receives geojson data, an array of objects, and a function to set the state of the markers.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';



function MyData ({data, markers, setMarkers})  {
    // data not null, return the geojson component      
    if (data) {  
      return <GeoJSON pathOptions={ { color: "red" } } data={data} eventHandlers={{
        // click handler for geojson component
        click:  (e) => {
          // push the latlng object to the markers array
          markers.push(e.latlng)
          // set the state using the setter...why does this not render markers?
          setMarkers(markers)
             
        }
        }}  />;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };


export default MyData
```

Here is my **MyMarkers** component which iterates through the array of markers which I pass it as a prop ideally creating Marker components at each position. (this doesn't work)

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Marker } from 'react-leaflet';


function MyMarkers ({markers}) {
   // check length of the markers
  if (markers.length > 0){
    // iterate through the array of markers creating a marker with unique id at given latlngs
    markers.map((position, id) => { 
      return <Marker key={id} position={position}/>
    })    

} else {
  return null;
}
};


export default MyMarkers
```

I'm able to draw my geojson data on the map but am unable to get markers to show up on click of my `<MyData/>` component.  What am I missing here?  My understanding is that when trying to update state of sibling components ( `<MyData/>` and `<MyMarkers/>` ) the state needs to be lifted to a common ancestor (`<App/>` in this case) which is what I have attempted to do.  How can I successfully update the state onclick from inside `<MyData/>` to render the markers?

**[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/w6dxo)** is a sandbox of the issue and code above as well.

Thanks

Comment: your demo is empty. no code, no running example

Comment: oh darn, I forgot to hit save. Sandbox example code added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-First you are mutating the array. As a result the component does not rerender. You should make a clone of markers and then push the new state.

```
<GeoJSON
        pathOptions={{ color: "red" }}
        data={data}
        eventHandlers={{
          // click handler for geojson component
          click: (e) => {
            const newMarkers=[...markers];
            newMarkers.push(e.latlng);
            console.log(newMarkers)
            setMarkers(newMarkers);
          }
        }}
      />
```

-Second you already check here for Markers to render `markers.length !== 0`, in my opinion it should be better above 0: `{markers.length > 0 && <MyMarkers markers={markers} />}`

Why recheck inside `Markers` component. Keep it simple:

```
function MyMarkers({ markers }) {      
    // iterate through the array of markers creating a marker with unique id at given latlngs
    return markers.map((position, id) => {
      return <Marker key={id} position={[position.lat, position.lng]} />;
    });
 
}
```

Last but not least the marker url icon is not correct. Replace it with

```
  iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
```

for instance

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-how-to-create-markers-on-click-of-geojson-component-dn1v8)

Comment: wow brilliant thanks for the help.  That works perfectly.  Fixing my logic with mutating the state helped me fix a bunch of other things as well.  Clearly there is much to learn. 
 Thanks!!